# Counting frequency in a cell of char in Matlab: fast code?

Tags: matlab

I have a `1x2` cell `A` in Matlab. `A{i}` is a cell of dimension `30494866x1` for `i=1,2`. `A{i}(j)` is a `1x21` char for `i=1,2` and `j=1,...,30494866`.

For example I report here `A{2}(1:3)`

```
'116374117927631468606'
'112188647432305746617'
'116374117927631468606'
```

I want to count how many times each `1x21` char in `A{2}` is repeated. For example, just considering `A{2}(1:3)`, I want to get

```
'116374117927631468606'  2
'112188647432305746617'  1
```

What I am doing at the moment is

```
a=unique(A{2},'stable'); 
b=cellfun(@(x) sum(ismember(A{2},x)),a);
```

However this is incredibly slow (running since yesterday). Do you have any suggestion on how I can speed up the code?

Comment: So you want to know how many times 1 is used, how many times 2 etc. Do you only have 0-9?

Comment: Or do you want frequency of 21-char strings?

Comment: The second. I have clarified to my question, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to know how many times each 21-char string used:

```
1) sort the cell
2) count how many times each string is used in a for loop.
```

Your code is O(n^2) so it's very slow. This should take less than a minute.

Based on your code

```
B=sort(A{2}); 
U=sort(unique(B)); 
C=zeros(numel(U),1); 
cnt = 1; 
for j=1:numel(B) 
    if strcmp(U(cnt),B(j))==1 
        C(cnt)=C(cnt)+1; 
    else
        cnt = cnt +1; 
        if cnt <= numel(U)
            C(cnt) = C(cnt)+1;
        end
    end 
end
```

Comment: OK, thanks. Something like this? `B=sort(A{2});
U=unique(B);
C=zeros(numel(U),1);
for i=1:numel(U)
for j=1:numel(A{2})
     if strcmp(U(i),A{2}(j))==1
          C(i)=C(i)+1;
     end
end
end`

Comment: Yes, precisely. How long does it take? Also could you test in a smaller set like size of A{2} =5

Comment: Why do I need to do `sort`?

Comment: Sorry, your code is not exactly what I said. This is still two for loops, still n^2. The reason you sorted is to be able to prevent the second for loop. Let me re-write the code. It is not going to be the most efficient way but still it will be quite fast.

Comment: Try this one, make sure there is no typo or small syntax error.

Comment: Thanks. I think this may be closer to what you suggest `B=sort(A{2});
U=sort(unique(B)); 
C=zeros(numel(U),1); 
cnt = 1;
for j=1:numel(A{2})
      if strcmp(U(cnt),B(j))==1
          C(cnt)=C(cnt)+1;  
      else
           cnt = cnt +1;
      end
 end`. Still, it does not work because we need also to update the index `j`

Comment: Now it is working, I tested on a small set on my computer. please check the new code

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the standard `unique`- `accumarray` couple:

```
data = {'116374117927631468606'
         '112188647432305746617'
         '116374117927631468606'};
[uu, ~,  ww] = unique(data, 'stable');
count = accumarray(ww, 1);
result = [uu, num2cell(count)];
```

Or,  a little more memory-efficient:

```
data = {'116374117927631468606'
         '112188647432305746617'
         '116374117927631468606'};
[~, vv,  ww] = unique(data, 'stable');
count = accumarray(ww, 1);
result = [data(vv) num2cell(count)];
```